# Is it possible to create another signal function instance?(restart it) Haskell

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, arrows

I'm going to present you my ultimate problem.

I'm trying to build a GUI app that generates some wave and displays it.

Generating the sound is done and working:

```
lastKarplus :: forall p. Clock p => Double -> SigFun p Double Double
lastKarplus m = proc input -> do
            rec added <- delayLine (m/(rate (undefined :: p)))  -< input + feedback
                feedback <- fb -< added
            outA -< added
```

which is a  part of a string function:

```
string :: Clock c => Int -> SigFun c () Double
string 1 =  proc flag -> do
          out <- lastKarplus2 535.3 <<< burst1 535.3 -< ()
          outA -< out
```

It produces time-varying Double values. They aree fed to Fourier transformat function and this data is fed to the graph I'm displaying

The problematic part:

```
fftEx :: UISF () ()
fftEx = let graLay = makeLayout (Stretchy 200) (Stretchy 300)
    in proc () -> do
    rec b1value <- withDisplay (button "Reset") -< ()
        b1pressed <- unique -< b1value
        graphData <- fftDataGenerator -< b1pressed
        _ <- realtimeGraph graLay 2 Black -< graphData
    outA -< ()



fftDataGenerator :: UISF  (SEvent Bool) [(Double, Time)]
fftDataGenerator = proc e -> do
            d <- clockedSFToUISF 0.1 $ toFFT $ K.string 1  -< ()
            let (s, fft) = unzip d
                (a1, _) =  unzip s
            outA -< zip a1 fft
```

At this point event **b1pressed** is ignored by the **fftDataGenerator** signal function. But I want it to behave like this:

- it doesn't start right away after launching the program
- event b1pressed can start the  signal function from time 0.

I tried adding state to the signal functions, something along these lines:
[Daniel Winograd-Cort - Effects, Asynchrony, and Choice in Arrowized Functional
Reactive Programming](http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/dwc-yale-formatted-dissertation.pdf) page 43, but it's too much for me, I have to say.

Even if I can remember if the funtion is running or not it always boils down to regenerating the wave from time zero.

I would love to know if it's even possible. If someone wants to see the rest of this "code" I will provide it.

Comment: which FRP and GUI library are you using?

Comment: @ErikAllik library for gui is UISF. And for sound - Euterpea.

Comment: very interesting paper btw. have you had any success though?

Comment: @ErikAllik I focused on other things. I don't want to have anything in common with functional GUIs. There are pain the ass. As a hobbyist haskeller I have too little knowledge. And I really need to finish my thesis so I abandoned the GUI idea :)

Comment: Understood. But actually functional GUI's are kind of becoming mainstream: just consider ReactJS and Angular 2.0 and many others — because it just scales and composes well. Also, Event Sourcing seems more mainstream than FRP but Event Sourcing is just a special case of FRP in disguise. So I think actually FP GUI's are pretty neat, just that you should choose a more mature library for real work, such as Reflex, Sodium or Reactive Banana.

Comment: @ErikAllik Euterpea (library I have to work with) uses a lot ideas from UISF so I didn't have a choice. But thanks for clearing the FRP GUII stuff out :)